# Docker compose external links alias with http protocol

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, php-curl

I have a problem using docker compose link alias. I host a PHP application on docker and use curl in the application

this is my *docker-compose.yml*

```
php:
    external_links:
        - apache:my-apache
```

That links is working. I have *my-apache* item on /etc/hosts

```
172.17.0.5  my-apache
```

But the problem comes when i use php curl to access *my-apache* service, since php curl requires the strict format : http://domain.com, and i am unable to use *http://domain.com* as an alias for docker link.

This will produce error

```
apache:http://domain.com
```

The error :

```
ERROR: for php  too many values to unpack
```

Any suggestions? 
Big Thanks